# Add more font in blazor editor SfDocumentEditorContainer font dropdown menu

Tags: fonts, blazor, editor, default, syncfusion

I am a beginner in blazor and use syncfusion components. I want to add fonts to **SfDocumentEditorContainer**  font dropdown menu.

I see syncfusion comment at

https://www.syncfusion.com/forums/157923/add-more-font-in-blazor-editor-document-component

and tried the below code:

```
<SfDocumentEditorContainer @ref="container" Height="580px" Width="1300px" EnableToolbar="true" EnableRtl=true DocumentEditorSettings="EditorSettings" >    
    <DocumentEditorContainerEvents Created="OnCreated" DocumentChanged="OnDocumentChange" ></DocumentEditorContainerEvents>
</SfDocumentEditorContainer>

@code {

    internal string DocumentName { get; set; }

    SfDocumentEditorContainer container;

    DocumentEditorSettingsModel EditorSettings = new DocumentEditorSettingsModel() { FontFamilies= new string[3] { "Algerian", "Arial","Tahoma" } };

}
```

but font dropdown menu always load by default fonts.

I use SyncFusion 20.3.0.47.

thanks for any body help.

Comment: The reference [link](https://www.syncfusion.com/forums/157923/add-more-font-in-blazor-editor-document-component?reply=SfYktV) includes an update from the Syncfusion Team. It looks like an internal issue to me that they will handle internally. Usually, they take two business days to further respond to a query/incident. Visit the link after a few days for a new update.

Answer (score 0):

We have confirmed the reported issue as a defect and logged a defect report. We will fix this issue in our EJ2 patch release which is scheduled for November 16, 2022.

You can track the status of the bug through the below feedback link:

https://www.syncfusion.com/feedback/38618/font-family-customization-is-not-working-in-properties-pane

Disclaimer: “Inclusion of this solution in the weekly release may change due to other factors including but not limited to QA checks and works reprioritization.”

Comment: We are glad to announce that our patch release (v20.3.57) has been rolled out successfully. In this release, we have added the fix for the reported issue. 

 

Please upgrade to the latest version packages to resolve this issue.     

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Syncfusion.Blazor.WordProcessor/

 

CDN link : https://cdn.syncfusion.com/blazor/20.3.57/syncfusion-blazor-documenteditor.min.js